MariaDB fulltext index tokenization rules / DOC_ID mapping
First question: is there a document that describes the rules how MariaDB builds the fulltext index words (for InnoDB)?
I set innodb_ft_min_token_size=1 to include also one letter words in the index. But this does not seem to work for words like "D'Artagnan": the "d" letter is not found in information_schema.INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE. It works for "D Artagnan".
So I assume that single letters that are followed by a quote are ignored when building the index?
You could also post the link to the source code file, but I don't know whether my C knowledge is sufficient ;-)
Second question: the doc (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/information-schema-innodb_ft_index_table-table/) states that information_schema.INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE.doc_id matches to the id column of the original table: "DOC_ID: Document ID of the newly added row, either an appropriate ID column or an internal InnoDB value." But this did not happen for me - the doc_id values do not match my ID column. I tried the datatypes "int" and "bigint".
Here is a script that demonstrates my question:
create table FulltextTest
(
  textid int not null,
  text varchar(254) not null
) ENGINE=INNODB CHARACTER SET utf8;
alter table FulltextTest add primary key FulltextTest_PK (textid);


insert into FulltextTest (textid, text) values (100, 'D''Artagnan, Lucas');

insert into FulltextTest (textid, text) values (200, 'De''Artagnan, Lucas');
insert into FulltextTest (textid, text) values (201, 'D Artagnan, Lucas');
insert into FulltextTest (textid, text) values (202, 'L''Artagnan, Lucas');
insert into FulltextTest (textid, text) values (203, 'M''Artagnan, Lucas');

alter table FulltextTest add FULLTEXT index FulltextTest_IXFULL1(text);


SET GLOBAL innodb_ft_aux_table='<insert_database_name>/fulltexttest';

select * from information_schema.INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE order by doc_id, position;

SET GLOBAL innodb_ft_aux_table=null;


drop table FulltextTest;

The select on information_schema.INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE returns this:



WORD
FIRST_DOC_ID
LAST_DOC_ID
DOC_COUNT
DOC_ID
POSITION




artagnan
2
6
5
2
2


lucas
2
6
5
2
12


de
3
3
1
3
0


artagnan
2
6
5
3
3


lucas
2
6
5
3
13


d
4
4
1
4
0


artagnan
2
6
5
4
2


lucas
2
6
5
4
12


artagnan
2
6
5
5
2


lucas
2
6
5
5
12


artagnan
2
6
5
6
2


lucas
2
6
5
6
12



The first two lines correspond to the first row of my sample data and so on.

To answer part one of my question myself: this was changed by https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-20797
So, I have to eliminate single letters before an apostrophe while splitting the search string into word fragments.
Before, my search was like this:
select * From FulltextTest where 
    MATCH(Text) against ('+d*, +artagnan*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0; 

It should be:
select * From FulltextTest where 
    MATCH(Text) against ('+artagnan*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0; 

To find the "D'" part, I have to combine it with a "like" query (as suggested here: MariaDB fulltext search with special chars and "word starts with"):
select * From FulltextTest where 
   MATCH(Text) against ('+artagnan*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0 and 
   Text like '%D''Artagnan%'; 

